# Why incorrectly added customise dictionary?

Tags: c#, wpf, spell-checking

To enter text, I use the RichTextBox.

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="FlowDocumentViewer" Language="en"/>
```

I turn on the spell checker. To support the Russian language, I add customise dictionary.

```
try
{
    this.FlowDocumentViewer.SpellCheck.SpellingReform = SpellingReform.PreAndPostreform;
    Uri uri = new Uri("Resources/Russian.lex", UriKind.Relative);
    if (!this.FlowDocumentViewer.SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries.Contains(uri))
    {
        this.FlowDocumentViewer.SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries.Add(uri);
    }
    this.FlowDocumentViewer.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

But it is not working correctly.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So what exactly is wrong?

Comment: The word "союз" is in the dictionary and spell checker his notes as incorrect. And offers to replace words that are not in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct answer: the dictionary should be encoded in UTF-16.